# How can I project this data correctly in node-mapnik?

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, mapnik, node-js

I'm trying to use [node-mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik) to rasterize vector data into a transparent image and overlay it onto a basemap.

I'm generating OpenStreetMap basemaps with [tile-stitch](https://github.com/ericfischer/tile-stitch).  That's working well.

I'm then using node-mapnik to read vector data from a geojson file and render to an image.  I'm getting the image okay, but the projection is off.

The coordinates are all EPSG:4326, decimal notation, derived from a slippy map.
My mapnik xml stylesheet looks like this

```
<Map background-color='#00000000' srs='+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'>
    <Style name='test style'>
        <Rule><PolygonSymbolizer fill='#bb5acc66' /><LineSymbolizer stroke='#3ea3df66' stroke-width='1' /></Rule>
    </Style>
    <Layer name='test' srs='+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'>
        <StyleName>test style</StyleName>
        <Datasource>
            <Parameter name='type'>geojson</Parameter>
            <Parameter name='file'>test.geojson</Parameter>
        </Datasource>
    </Layer>
</Map>
```

My geojson looks like this:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -1.182891726493835, 51.630744982473551 ], [ -1.183235049247742, 51.630671725935755 ], [ -1.183497905731201, 51.630445295887 ], [ -1.183481812477112, 51.630258823233 ], [ -1.183358430862427, 51.630108978580999 ], [ -1.183213591575622, 51.630029061230999 ], [ -1.182989378008187, 51.630094380903088 ], [ -1.18303120136261, 51.630212204949991 ], [ -1.183058023452759, 51.630352059655998 ], [ -1.182972192764282, 51.630468604915002 ], [ -1.18278980255127, 51.630571830465001 ], [ -1.182720065116882, 51.630675055780998 ], [ -1.182703971862793, 51.630718343745997 ], [ -1.182891726493835, 51.630744982473551 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -1.181958317756653, 51.630367044063 ], [ -1.182041466236115, 51.630565170758999 ], [ -1.182301640510559, 51.630656741628989 ], [ -1.182315051555634, 51.630578490169995 ], [ -1.18239551782608, 51.630508563219998 ], [ -1.182478666305542, 51.630385358331999 ], [ -1.182626187801361, 51.630297116786998 ], [ -1.182596683502197, 51.63016059179499 ], [ -1.182666420936584, 51.629989102503011 ], [ -1.182325780391693, 51.629940818994001 ], [ -1.182111203670502, 51.629947478791003 ], [ -1.1820387840271, 51.630093994089002 ], [ -1.181958317756653, 51.630367044063 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -1.182666420936584, 51.629989102503011 ], [ -1.18283862812109, 51.630068380938702 ], [ -1.182989378008187, 51.630094380903088 ], [ -1.18303120136261, 51.630212204949991 ], [ -1.183058023452759, 51.630352059655998 ], [ -1.182972192764282, 51.630468604915002 ], [ -1.18278980255127, 51.630571830465001 ], [ -1.182720065116882, 51.630675055780998 ], [ -1.182703971862793, 51.630718343745997 ], [ -1.182395517689429, 51.630700862234136 ], [ -1.182301640510559, 51.630656741628989 ], [ -1.182315051555634, 51.630578490169995 ], [ -1.18239551782608, 51.630508563219998 ], [ -1.182478666305542, 51.630385358331999 ], [ -1.182626187801361, 51.630297116786998 ], [ -1.182596683502197, 51.63016059179499 ], [ -1.182666420936584, 51.629989102503011 ] ] ] } }]}
```

The data on the slippy map looks like this:

[image]

but the mapnik image looks like this:

[image]

I'm giving tile-stitch and mapnik the same bounds, and the same image dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the node mapnik wasn't reprojecting to EPSG:3857, which it uses internally.
If I reproject the data before passing it to mapnik then it works.